# Which SQL Server database settings fall under ALTER DATABASE SCOPED CONFIGURATION vs ALTER DATABASE SET syntax?

Tags: sql-server, configuration

I have noticed that there are two command syntaxes to change database configuration settings in SQL Server - ALTER DATABASE SCOPED CONFIGURATION and ALTER DATABASE SET. However, I am unclear on which database settings fall under each syntax.

For example, I know that database compatibility is a database-specific setting, but it uses the ALTER DATABASE SET syntax. This makes me wonder why it does not use the ALTER DATABASE SCOPED CONFIGURATION syntax.

So, my question is: Do you have any mental guide that help identify which database settings fall under which syntax? I would appreciate any insights or information on this topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A fair few of the original things that were enabled by the  `ALTER DATABASE SCOPED CONFIGURATION` syntax were things that used to be available only at an instance level via trace flags or `sp_configure`. Maybe you could use that as a heuristic. - [Martin Smith](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/3690/martin-smith)

For some reason, `compatibility_level` has its [own documentation page](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-compatibility-level) (is not documented with the other `SET` options). I know that most scoped configs are performance related (but not all). Apart from that I go by the documentation when I'm uncertain. - [Tibor Karaszi](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/151544/tibor-karaszi)